# TypeScript "Duplicate function implementation" because I am calling the function?

Tags: typescript

I'm just getting back into Typescript after working with it for a few weeks about a couple months ago... so I'm still new to it. (FYI: I know the code is non-sense)

My code is giving me an error - "Duplicate function implementation.ts(2393)".

The error goes away when I change the name of the call or the function definition.

Since my intellisense says I have one overload, my guess is that TSLint thinks the call is another definition, but why?

[image]

Is there some fundamental concept to typescript that I am missing here?

```
function myComponent(a: string): any {
const element = document.createElement('div');

element.innerText = "sefsdfsdfsdfs";

return element;
}

document.body.appendChild(myComponent("asda"));
```

Update: I guess in the real world it doesn't make sense to have functions outside of classes anyway, but still I would like to understand why this shows up. i.e. If there is something i can change in tsconfig.json.

Comment: Can you add the actual code as text? The code in the image seems different than the code you've pasted here.

Comment: @Carcigenicate you’re right in the image the function is defined twice lol

Comment: That's the intellisense popup

Comment: As others have noted, there's nothing wrong with the code you've posted that would throw any errors.  Are you sure you're not defining something with the same name earlier in the file?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the same issue. But I had similar on my pet project. I was creating many files which had the same function names inside, and TS was treating them as things in one namespace, that is why there were name conflicts. The fix was adding anything as exported from the file/module, so like `export function myComponent`. Of course if my theory is correct, then you need to have second file with the same `myComponent` named used.